# Qual o melhor método de carregar arquivos JS?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5, desempenho

Eu tento trabalhar com os código da forma que me de o maior aproveitamento possível do que foi escrito, com isso, pra cada recurso que eu vá precisar fazer em javascript/jQuery eu controlo a versão individual de cada coisa com git.

Controlando essa versão individual, acontece que eu acabo tendo muitos arquivos a serem importados no carregamento do sistema, meu carregamento possui uma lista como essa (bem resumida):

masker-0.0.5.js

navigation-0.0.1.js

validator-0.2.1.js

tiles-effects-1.0.0.js

tiles-navigation-1.0.0.js

Incluindo os carregamentos externos, e internos de terceiros a lista fica realmente gigante, pois só os recursos relacionados com Bootstrap CSS ja dão ~30 inclusões só de arquivos .js, sem falar nas folhas de estilo.

Voltando aos meus arquivos individuais, eles são relativamente pequenos, tendo em média 3k de caracteres.

Meu carregamento atual em ambiente de desenvolvimento é feito com uma classe em PHP:

```
    class local__jsPackages
    {

        public static function get_packages()
        {
            $files = '';
            $packages = self::packages();
            foreach ($packages as $import)
            {
                $path = $import['path'];
                $file = $import['file'];
                $version = $import['version'];
                $files .= '<script src="' . $path . '/' . $file . '' . $version . '.js"></script>';
            }
            return $files;
        }

    private static function packages()
        {

            $packages = [
                //Plugin Bootstrap
                '0' => [
                    'path' => '../theme/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js',
                    'file' => 'bootstrap',
                    'version' => (string) '.min'
                ]
                //Dentro da array seguem todas as inclusões locais
           ];
           return $packages;
     }
}
```

E quando é passado para produção, eu agrupo manualmente tudo em um unico arquivo gigante, esse é a parte do processo com problema.

> Qual é a melhor forma de se CARREGAR muitos arquivos/métodos/plugins em javascript ?

PS: Eles devem ser carregados todos de uma vez, pois a aplicação não deve permitir que o usuário atualize a página sem deslogar.

Comment: 'A aplicação não deve permitir que o usuário atualize a página sem deslogar', ?

Comment: O botão 'f5' foi desabilitado, quando o usuário aperta 'f5' o sistema solicita que seja feito logout, e caso ele atualize pelo navegador tem de logar novamente.

Comment: Entendi, vamos deixar que alguém responda mais precisamente, mas na minha opnião, carregar front-end no servidor era um método muito usado quando javascript ainda não era tão difundido, hoje não existe porque fazer isso, provavelmente você possui algum vicio de linguagem (no caso PHP) e acaba usando o mesmo, para outras finalidades.

Comment: Eu realmente tenho esse 'problema' com o PHP, eu detesto programar front-end, e acabo por gerar até um simples 'button' com uma classe em PHP, esse é um dos motivos por eu não saber como operar muito bem com JS.

Comment: Normal kk, abordagem front-end no servidor hoje só em frameworks como ruby on rails e outras derivadas, em rails por exemplo você gera um crud com todo o esquema front-end em minutos, sem precisar por a mão no html, somente no css para dar um 'corzinha' dps, a propósito hoje já existem frameworks PHP que se equiparam ao rails, não sei te dizer quais, mas ouvi isso dos mestres https://hipsters.tech/a-vez-do-ruby-on-rails-hipsters-52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnthraxisBR, vou deixar aqui minha sugestão aqui como resposta para ficar melhor para lermos, os comentários é muito limitado

O Grunt faz concatenção de arquivos JS e CSS além da minificação dos mesmos automaticamente.

Por exemplo:

No blog da minha esposa, uso o Grunt para concatenar e minificar 3 arquivos

```
'js/jquery.js',
'js/what-input.js',
'js/app.js'
```

Então o uglfy do meu Gruntfile.js é assim:

```
uglify: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                expand: true,
            },
        files: {
                'js/app.min.js': [
                    'js/jquery.js',
                    'js/what-input.js',
                     'js/app.js'
                ],
                }
            },
        },
```

Logo, os 3 arquivos serão concatenados e minificados num unico arquivo: app.min.js.

**mas se eu quiser rodar isso sem saber o nome do arquivo?**

Muito fácil, dentro do seu files: {} iria ficar assim:

```
'js/app.min.js': [
    'js/*.js //vai pegar tudo que tem extensão .JS
 ],
```

**E se eu quiser não rodar um único arquivo?**

Basta adicionar uma exclamação na frente do caminho arquivo assim:

```
'js/app.min.js': [
   '!js/nomearquivo.js // vai ignorar esse cara na concatenação e minificação
],
```

Eu costumo criar uma função PHP para controlar a versão

```
function get_file_version(){
 echo '20170801';
}
```

e para finalizar, eu chamo o arquivo no html da seguinte maneira:

```
<script src="js/app.min.js?version=<?php get_file_version(); ?>"></script>
```

Porque?

Porque o navegador faz cache do arquivo e toda vez que é modificado o arquivo .JS é necessário que o navegador releia o arquivo para as mudanças surtirem efeito. Toda vez que voce muda o valor, voce força o navegador a ler o arquivo.

https://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Espero ter ajudado